# Reactive plot using selected variables but crashes if facet used, Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I'm using Shiny and the famous data set, iris, to create a reactive plot.

I was able to make the plot reactive to the point that the user gets to choose which variable is used for each axis. However, I would like to plot for more than one species of iris using facet_grid function. If I pick more than one species, the shiny crashes.

Here's ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("3 species of iris"),
sidebarPanel(
  checkboxGroupInput("Species", label = h4("Pick the Species"), choices =     levels(iris$Species)),
  actionButton("lr",label = h5("Draw Linear Regression Line")),
  radioButtons("xaxis", label= h4("Pick the variable for x-axis"), choices = names(iris[0:4])),
  radioButtons("yaxis", label= h4("Pick the variable for y-axis"), choices = names(iris[0:4]))
  ),

  mainPanel( 
      div('Correlation between the Length and Width for Petal and Sepal from each of 3 species'),
      plotOutput('iris_plot')
)))
```

And here's server.R:

```
library(shiny)
# Plotting 
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)

# Shiny server 
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$iris_plot <- renderPlot({

if(is.null(input$Species))
    return()    
sp <- iris[iris$Species %in% input$Species,]

# Draw a plot for any checked iris species. 

if(is.null(input$xaxis))
  return()
if(is.null(input$yaxis))
  return()

g <- ggplot(sp, aes_string(x= input$xaxis, y=input$yaxis)) +
    geom_point(shape = sp$Species, size=2) +  
    facet_grid(Species ~ .)

print(g)

# The action button's initial value is set to 0 and the increment increases by 1 each time it is clicked.
# Use this logic to make the button capable of both drawing and removing the linear regression line. 

if((input$lr)%%2==0)
  return()
isolate({lm <- g + geom_smooth(aes_string(x= input$xaxis, y=input$yaxis), method=lm)
print(lm)})


})

})
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aesthetics shape takes factor/integer as the input.
Convert to factor.

```
g <- g + geom_point(data = sp, aes(shape = factor(Species), size=2))
```

Comment: Hi @sirujam, unfortunately that didn't work. The error message says a continuous variable cannot be mapped to shape :(

Comment: Use g <- g + geom_point(data = sp, aes(shape = factor(Species), size=2)).

Comment: Great it works! I must have missed something before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Within the Shinyapps.io website, you can click on the application that you are running and click on "Logs" to get more specific details about what is causing the error.

Additionally, you can use:

```
shinyapps::showLogs()
```